# jQuery in chrome extension $ is not defined | How to use jQuery in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I realize this may seem similar to another question, but the solutions to that one did not work for me.
I am trying to use jQuery in my content scripts, yet I keep getting an error:
[image: error]

Of course, I have jQuery downloaded locally, and added  a reference to it in my Manifest file
[image: manifest file]

I have also tried creating a new script DOM before the rest of my Javascript is ran, yet I still have this issue
[image: [![enter image description here][3]][3] (this is probably done wrong, don't need anyone commenting on it lmao, I screenshotted it]

Any idea on how I can get this working?

Comment: If you open the developer console does a request for the `jquery.js` get sent, and return a 200?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't click the reload icon on your extension's card in chrome://extensions page or you didn't reload the tab. Note that there's no need to create a `script` element as it runs in an entirely different *context*: the [page context](/a/9517879).